# Python re wrong output

Tags: python

I want to find the position of '.', but when i run code below:

```
text = 'Hello world.'
pattern = '.'
search = re.search(pattern,text)
print(search.start())
print(search.end())
```

Output is:

```
0
1
```

Place of '.' isn't 0 1.
So why is it giving wrong output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use find method for this task.

```
my_string = "test"
s_position = my_string.find('s')
print (s_position)
```

**Output**

```
2
```

If you really want to use RegEx be sure to escape the dot character or it will be interpreted as a special character.

The dot in RegEx matches any character except the newline symbol.

```
text = 'Hello world.'
pattern = '\.'
search = re.search(pattern,text)
print(search.start())
print(search.end())
```